# Drools/Scala - Create var/val inside DRL

Tags: scala, drools

I'm trying to use Drools with Scala and i would like to know if it is possible to call a chain of events and create var/val when the function has a return.

Here is what i'm trying but i'm stuck:

```
import com.models.*
import com.service.*

rule "First Fule"
when
    person:Person(name == 'aa')
then
    //Here should return a string
    //and i should set this string
    //something like:
    //var x = new Person(ServiceLongDong.sayHello(), person.age, person.name)
    //or var y = ServiceLongDong.sayHello();
    ServiceLongDong.sayHello();
    ServiceLongDong.finish(x);
end
```

Is possible to create varl/vals and pass it to another function?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules aren't functions (or methods) and don't "return" values or objects. The right hand side is just Java code. You can call static methods, but stick to correct Java syntax:

```
Person p = new Person(ServiceLongDong.sayHello(),
                      person.age, person.name);
ServiceLongDong.sayHello();
ServiceLongDong.finish(x);
```

This can't be correct Java if ServiceLongDong is a class:

```
... = ServiceLongDong().sayHello();
```

Comment: Scala has factory classes that are used as OP mentions, so it's valid syntax. ServiceLongDong() returns an instance for which sayHello() can be called. For those to be available with Drools, you'd have to know how Scala compiler sets the API visibility *outside* for Drools to have access. Might be easier to write a Java adapter for this purpose, though.

Comment: @kaskelotti Drools RHS (the code between `then` and `end`) is Java, so you can't use anything else there. Note that I wrote "can't be correct **Java**" and not "can't be correct".

Comment: That's what I meant. Scala is compiled to Java equivalent bytecode. In order to use such a Scala construct in Drools, you need to know how the interface is visible outside.

Comment: so if i would like to return something, i need to call a function that should do it (i.e.: call a method to display a message on console)?

Comment: You have better options than that. Apart from more suitable ways to log: see the Drools documentation regarding DRL globals and truth maintenance.